# VPN won't connect after most recent update

Tags: 16.04, vpn, openvpn

I haven't been on my Ubuntu machine in about a week.  When I turned it on, first thing I did was install the most recent updates and restart.

After installing the install, I tried to connect to my VPN, but it is completely unresponsive.  It won't even give the animation like it is attempting to connect.  Nothing inside the VPN menu responds in any way, not even the "configure VPN" option.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and not resolved it yet.

However, it appears to be a GUI problem as the command line works.

Try the following from the command line:

```
nmcli con show
nmcli con up "<VPN-Conn-Name>"
```

The first command lists all connections, then second starts the VPN.

Comment: Hm, odd.  I'm able to connect that way, but when I go to https://ipleak.net/ it shows that my IP has changed, but I'm still leaking DNS.